# Cannot uninstall incorrect version Erlang on RHEL 6.x

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, erlang

### Issue

I am setting up a RHEL 6.X server to house my RabbitMQ test environment.  I need to install Erlange 16 or higher to work correctly with the latest version of RabbitMQ (3.6.x I believe).  However, I currently have Erlang 14 on the system.  I tried to remove it via yum however yum is saying it is not installed.

```
yum remove erlang
```

However when I run

```
$ erl -v
```

I get the following

```
Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
```

And there exists a erlang directory

```
/usr/lib64/erlang/
```

With the following sub directories

```
bin  erts-5.8.5  lib  man  releases  usr
```

How should I go about uninstalling this version of Erlang so I can install a new version?  One peice of information that may be helpful.  After the first successful install of the old version I actually did run yum remove and it appeared to work. However when I then tried to install the newer version it was stating the conflicts and I then found the aforementioned directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

erlang is made up of a number of RPM packages which are installed automatically as depependencies when you do `yum install erlang`. One of these packages contains the `erl` script.

However when you do `yum remove erlang` the additional packages aren't automatically removed.

You can remove all the packages by looking at yum's history (using the `yum history list` command - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303754/how-to-remove-all-installed-dependent-packages-while-removing-a-package-in-cento for more details) and removed the packages installed as part of the erlang installation transaction.

Or, in this case, you could probably just get a list of installed erlang components using `yum list installed | grep erlang` and remove those packages.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. `yum list installed | grep erlang` shows the installed erlang packages which can then be removed with `yum remove erlang-*`

Answer (score 1):

uninstall erlang by yum need to do like this:
first, find out erlang-erts by

> yum list installed | grep erlang-erts

to see what is you erts full name then

> yum remove erlang-erts.x86_64

it should remove erlang from yum